# Clue: same or different guess and accusation in the same turn

Tags: cluedo

When playing Clue can your guess and accusation be different in the same turn or do you have to wait till your next turn for making an accusation that is different from your previous guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggestion and accusation don't have to be the same and can contain completely different aspects. There is no mention in the rules about them having to have anything that match.

It is very possible to use the suggestion to determine the correct parts and then make the accusation right away.

[Rules](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/clue/game-rules.php)

> If you think you have solved the crime (by deduction), you can end your turn by making an accusation and name any three elements.
> you can say: "I accuse (suspect) of committing the crime in the (room) with the (weapon)".
> Then, you must look secretly at the cards in the envelope to check if your suggestion is correct.
> If you are correct, you can place the 3 cards face-up on the table to prove it and you won the game!

Comment: You for got to include: "*If no one is able to prove your suggestion false, you may either end your turn or make an accusation.*"

Comment: @ForgetIwaseverhere I didn't forget to include it, rather it wasn't relevant to the question of the suggestion and the accusation being different. You are able to make a suggestion that others can prove false and also make an accusation on the same turn.